# Android : contradiction between 2 HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, url, android-activity

im new android developer and i will try the best to explein my problem 
 i have **2 activies**
they both have listview's **that use the same custom Adapter**
each acitvity has her own url for server requesting.

This is the class where i send the url and get back the stream data

```
public class HTTPDataHandler {

    static String stream = null;

    public HTTPDataHandler(){
    }

    public String GetHTTPData(String urlString){

        Log.v("HTTP handler", "Get HTTP DATA" );



        try{
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Check the connection status
            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                // if response code = 200 ok
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                // Read the BufferedInputStream
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                stream = sb.toString();
                // End reading...............

                // Disconnect the HttpURLConnection
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            else
            {

                // Do something
                Log.v("HTTP handler", "Not connected or got wrong data" );
            }
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {

        }
        // Return the data from specified url
        return stream;
    }
}
```

My first activity works fine and the listew shows with no problems
but in my second activity i put the right url but it returns me the stream of the first acitvity.
i debbuged that and i saw that in the part of

```
 if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
```

i got else, and it returns me the first acitvity data instead of the data in activity 2 url.

What can cause it?
is it related to my "static String stream"?

im sorry for the bad english
and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

#### edit 2:

From your comments, the 505 error reads:

> 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
>
> The server does not support, or refuses to support, the HTTP protocol version that was used in the request message. The server is indicating that it is unable or unwilling to complete the request using the same major version as the client, as described in section 3.1, other than with this error message. The response SHOULD contain an entity describing why that version is not supported and what other protocols are supported by that server.

#### edit:

You should save the Adapter or any related data yourself locally (I do believe HTTP Urlconnection does this) or some sort of cache, then read repeatedly from that cache, and only update the repository on a pattern, such as a time difference, timeout, cache-control or a default personnal directive.

Note that internet usually costs money. Save it, and your user will be happier.

#### Original

Please, check code 304 [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html); that reads:

> 304 Not Modified
>
> If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD respond with this status code. The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Comment: Thank you sir. the only common things in what im trying to do is the same adapter for the listviews and the same object type data, apart from that, the url's different,the activities and the purpose of what im trying to do. i used that class for other url calls in my app and it worked fine, i think the solution you suggest is more for getting and updating data instead of my purpose 2 different url requests for different data

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I misread the question. Tell me this, when you Log `urlConnection.getResponseCode()`, what value does it show? Because a 304 should only happen on identical `GET` requests, any change should yeld back a new `200 Response Code`. If the problem is persisting on different codes, can you ensure you are not sharing the Network Adapter or even your own `Connection Object`, thus causing a bad Response from the server? Also, as my opinion, please check out `Volley`, on Google. I use it, and found it perfect (and `HttpURLConnection ` is deprecated anyway). It fullfills the network role

Comment: i digged more and i found the request code i get is 505 and the error stream buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource@e2e940e).inputStream()

Comment: Your Server cant or wont reply to your HTTP request, under your major request (lets guess its `HTTP 1.1`). Try manually remaking the `HTTP GET` request with `HTTP 1.0` ([source](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html)). Or may I suggest you implement `Volley`. I myself started learning the `URLConnection` class for Network data transfer, and got along it, then completely abandonned it, when it deprecated. Note that some Android devices will have a blank `class`, that will never do its functions (does not appear to be your case), but never fail method calls (always returning null)

Comment: Thank you, i found that  the url had an empty space and solved the problem, frustrated that the url worked in other platforms but in android doesn't, cause me to dig the hell of that.

Comment: If you answered your question, and believe this cannot help others, then please, delete the question. If you believe this could help others (the way the question is), then create an Answer yourself, and check it as solved. Finally, I still insist that, if you are going to support this in many devices, and expect a product to behave similarly in different scenarios, then at least Google `Android Volley`, and read about. It is a good API for applications that use network.